# Routing question in nested resources form for ".each do" structure - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, datamapper, nested-forms

In my routes i have:

```
resources :accounts do
    resources :transfers
      put '/transfers/:id(.:format)' => 'transfers#accept'
  end
```

In my model:

```
class Transfer
  include DataMapper::Resource
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :alias_from, "Alias"
  belongs_to :alias_to, "Alias"

class Account
  include DataMapper::Resource
  belongs_to :user
  has n, :transfers
```

In my view:

```
  <% @transfers_in.each do |income|%>
  Amount: <%= income.amount%> <%= income.account.currency%> 
      <% form_for ([???, income]), :as => :transfer, :url => {:controller=>'transfers', :action => 'accept'} do |f|%>
      Choose the account <%= f.collection_select :account, @accounts, :name, :name %> 
      <%= f.submit :value => "Accept" %>
      <% end %>
 <% end %>
```

How should I call for the account here, if here @transfers_in is called by other association?

```
@aliases = @owner.aliases.all()
@transfers_in = @aliases.transfers_in.all()
```

I've tried something like

```
<% @acc = Account.all()%>
          <% @trs = @acc.transfers.get(:id => income.account)%>
          <% form_for ([@trs, income]), ....
```

but that gave me

> No route matches
>   {:controller=>"transfers",
>   :action=>"accept"}

In rake routes such route exists.

Would be thankful for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In your routes, you should have better results using the macros Rails provides for routing. Instead of doing the old-style route map, try:

```
resources :accounts do
  resources :transfers do
    put 'accept', :on => :member
  end
end
```

The router is really smart when it comes to RESTful routes, but when you start manually mapping things, it can get confused... especially when you're doing it inside of nested, RESTful routes.